# Rails reset_counters in counter_cache with conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, counter-cache

I've two counter_cache, one for total number of `campaign_codes` and one only when `campaign_code` was used - `campaign_codes.where(state: 'used')`. To update total number of `campaign_codes` in the `rails c` I used script like:

`CreditCampaign.reset_counters(CreditCampaign.first.id, :campaign_codes)`

but this works only for total number of campaign_codes. How to setup the script in console for used campaign?

`CampaignCode` model

```
class CampaignCode < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :credit_campaign, counter_cache: :total_campaign_codes_amount
  belongs_to :used_credit_campaign, -> { where(state: 'used') }, class_name: 'CampaignCode', counter_cache: :used_campaign_codes_amount, optional: true
end
```

`CreditCampaign` model

```
class CreditCampaign < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :campaign_codes
end
```

Comment: Did my [previous comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58271158/1954610) help?

Comment: @TomLord Thanks for that! It was helpful but now if I manage how to update manually this counter cache I think I will be able to implement this solution to my endpoint, like with `total_campaign_codes_amount`

Comment: `... , class_name: 'CampaignCode', ...`  Are you sure this is correct?

Comment: @chumakoff Yup it is

Comment: `campaign_code` belongs to `campaign_code`?

Comment: `campaign_code` belongs to `used_credit_campaign`

Comment: `used_credit_campaign` is a `CreditCampaign`. So it must be `class_name: 'CreditCampaign'`

Comment: @chumakoff in such case I should move `used_campaign_codes_amount` to the `CreditCampaign` model which I don't want to do. However I think @TomLord is right, counter cache doesn't work in scope, in that case I will leave it only for `total_campaign_codes_amount`.